# su - <username> hangs if I added a line in /etc/bashrc

Tags: centos, users, bashrc, su

I added this line to `/etc/bashrc` file

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/glibc-2.14/lib
```

I log in as root throw SSH normally, but if I wanted to change my user by

```
su - myusername
```

**the terminal hangs**. If I removed this line every thing works fine.

How to fix this and put this line in the `bashrc` and be able to switch my user ?